# Grammar question: plural nouns and verb forms

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

1. What was his and her intent when they left？
   I saw this sentence in a book but shouldn't it be "were" instead of "was", since "his and her" is a plural noun?
2. Early to bed and early to rise _________ a man healthy, wealthy and wise.
   My assessment book said the answer is  "makes", not "make". Why is that? Isn't it a plural noun when we use the conjunction "and" ?

Comment: (2) This old proverb presumably treats 'early to bed and early to rise' as a single description of a lifestyle.

Comment: It looks klunky with ***his and her** intent*, but if you wanted to pluralise the verb to ***were***, you'd also have to pluralise the object noun ***intents*** - which would be even worse! The easiest way to rephrase into something more natural is to change the subject - *What was **their** intent when they left?* Note that your version already refers to them as ***they*** anyway. If it's important (for some strange reason) to explicitly convey that ***they*** refers to "him and her", just switch the references around: *What was their intent when **he and she** left?*

Comment: You're assuming that _his intent_ and _her intent_ were different, and so should be plural. That could be the case, but it's unusual. As FumbleFingers says, even with "they" we would usually talk about "their intent" with no awkwardness.

Comment: And the apparently 'common-intent-forcing' _What was their intent when they left?_ is, because of the availability of the _distributive singular_, still a possibility when the questioner knows 'they' intended different things and/or wants two different answers.